# Filter Prestashop Product that appartain at more categories

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i have two categories: Brand and Parts.
How can i filter a prestashop product after user click on a category ?
For example:

First Category:
BRAND -> CHEVROLET -> CHEVROLET CAMARO

Second Category
PARTS -> BODY -> BUMPER

I'd like that a user, after click on Chevrolet Camaro can choose the parts of his interest, so for example click on bumper for all bumpers of camaro.

How can i do it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use prestashop block later in category page to filter product.